# Getting weird outputs when I try to print my multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

When I try to print this program it outputs null 12 times all in  new line, so can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I want this program to print the object and its weight in one line and then print the next object and its weight in another line and so on...

```
public class ojArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //makes a new multidimensial array
    //the first dimension holds the name of the object 
    //the second dimension holds the weight
    //the 4's in this case show the maximum space the array can hold
    String[][] objectList = new String[4][4];

    objectList[1][0] = "Teapot";
    objectList[0][1] = String.valueOf(2);

    objectList[2][0] = "Chesterfield";
    objectList[2][2] = String.valueOf(120);

    objectList[3][0] = "Laptop";
    objectList[3][3] = String.valueOf(6);

    //printing the array
    for (int i = 1; i < objectList.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < objectList.length; j++) {
            int k = 1;
            System.out.println(objectList[1][1]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is kind of a bad way of doing this. Instead of having one whole dimension for your names, and one for your data (16 in total) you should use the first item in your second array to hold names, and the second to hold data (so: `[0][0]`, `[0][1]` for your first item, then `[1][0]` and `[1][1]` for your second and so on (making 8 in total - half the space your current one takes! And no null spots...)

Comment: that's brilliant! Hats off to you sir! But wouldn't that mean that,[0] [0] would be skipped?

Comment: `[0][0]` would be the position that you give the name of the first item. Draw a literal graph of it on paper if it will help you visualize it, with the first dimension being X and the second dimension being Y.

Comment: @Jeff would that mean the third item would be [0][2]. Sorry but sometimes I have difficulty grasping concepts :p

Comment: Think of the first dimension being the item in question, and the second dimension being the fields. So `[0][...]` specifies something about the first item, and `[2][...]` specifies something about the third dimension. `[...][0]` specifies the name of an item, while `[...][1]` specifies the weight of some item. Combined, `[2][0]` is the name if the third item, and `[2][1]` is the weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing `[1][1]` instead of `[i][j]`.

Try:

```
for (int i = 1; i < objectList.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < objectList.length; j++) {
        int k = 1;
        System.out.println(objectList[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Oh yeah, and you initialize `[0][1]` instead of `[1][1]`. Try:

```
objectList[1][0] = "Teapot";
objectList[1][1] = String.valueOf(2);
```

Comment: Thank you! I put in [1][1] to test something and must've forgotten it but the second part was the answer I was looking for! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To print on the same line you will not be able to use the `println()` method each time in your inner loop, either create a string for each object in the inner loop and then put println in the outer loop or use `print()` in the inner loop then print a new line in the outer loop.

Like

```
for (int i = 1; i < objectList.length; i++) 
{
        String output = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < objectList.length; j++) 
        {
            int k = 1;
            output += objectList[i][j] + " ";
        }
        println(output);
}
```

Comment: Good call, didn't spot that one. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use variables while printing the array instead of `[1][1]` try `[i][j]`

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you simply print `objectList[1][1]`, which you never initialized, so it is null.  You loop 3 * 4 = 12 times, so you get 12 null's.  If you print `objectList[i][j]`, you will get the contents of the array.